# How can I enable intellisense for the C# Interactive window in Visual Studio Professional 16.8.5?

Tags: visual-studio

When I am writing code in the C# Interactive window I noticed that there was no intellisense. I have seen several articles that say intellisense is supported in the C# Interactive window. I assume that the problem must be with my installation, but I'm not sure what to check to get this working.

How can I enable the intellisense?

Comment: Are you using Resharper?  I once heard its intellisense could disable VS intellisense in the Immediate Window, but I don't know if it is still a problem.

Comment: No. I don't have ReSharper.

Comment: I left the C# Interactive window loaded while working for a while. When I checked back the intellisense was working. I must need time to initialize.